# Check all row combination and find out the rows with maximum mean on a particular column of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2    ind
 A        1      0
 B        2      1
 C        10     2
 D        5      3
 E        11     4
 F        4      5
 G        7      6
 H        20     7
 I        33     8
 J        24     9
 K        22     10
 L        5      11
```

Now I want to create a window of with minimum size 1/4 of the length of data frame and maximum size is total length of the data frame.

Now I want to try every window with step size 1 and calculate the mean. I want to see in which combination the min is maximum.

I have used following code and it gives correct result. But as I have used for loop the execution time is poor.

```
start_index=[]
stop_index=[]
average=[]
min_window=len(df)//4
for i in range(min_window,len(df)):
    for j in range(0,len(df)-i):
        t_df=df.iloc[j:j+i,:]
        avg=np.mean(list(t_df.col2))
        start_index.append(t_df.ind.values[0])
        stop_index.append(t_df.ind.values[-1])
        average.append(avg)

# now we can find the rows with max average from the indices.
```

As because of for loop the execution time is poor so, I am looking for some pandas shortcut/python trick to do the same task most efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is use 
[strides](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html) solution:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

min_window=len(df)//4
for i in range(min_window,len(df)):
    avg = rolling_window(df['col2'].values, i).mean(axis=1)
    ind = rolling_window(df['ind'].values, i)
    start = ind[:, 0]
    end = ind[:, -1]
    min_idx = np.argmax(avg)
    #print (min_idx)

    print (f'start is {start[min_idx]}, end is {end[min_idx]} max is {avg[min_idx]}')
```

How it working - It create 2d array by window size, so you can get `mean` per `axis=1`, then get `start` and `end` by selecting first and last `'columns'` and for maximum `average` is used [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for indices of maximum values and then indexing for values of `ind`:

```
print (rolling_window(df['col2'].values, 3))
[[ 1  2 10]
 [ 2 10  5]
 [10  5 11]
 [ 5 11  4]
 [11  4  7]
 [ 4  7 20]
 [ 7 20 33]
 [20 33 24]
 [33 24 22]
 [24 22  5]]
```